# Android save image to PHP server

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

Basically im trying to post an image a user selects to my server and save it on there.

PHP FILE:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/functions.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/config.php';

    $image = $_POST["avatar"];
    $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];

    $files = glob('avatars/*.jpg');
    $name = count($files) + 1;

    $decodedImage = base64_decode($image);
    file_put_contents("avatars/" . $name . ".jpg", $decodedImage);
?>
```

Android

```
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

        String base64avatar = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String dataString = "user_id=" + userID + "&avatar=" + base64avatar;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL_OMITTED);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(dataString);
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            Log.d("Response code",conn.getResponseCode() + "");

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

A file gets created on the server, but its not readable. When I set the compressformat to PNG weirdly enough a readable file is created, but its corrupt so its mostly black instead of the uploaded image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the base64 wasn't URL_SAFE.
By changing `Base64.Default to Base64.URL_SAFE` and adding

```
$image = str_replace(array('-', '_'), array('+', '/'), $image);
```

to the php file to decode the URL_SAFE string.

I'm sure this probably isn't the way to do it, but it works.